# Testing ruby with rspec for file name and STDIN with while gets

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm writing a simple program that can take input from two sources, either a file name passed in or STDIN. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around testing that functionality. Do I need to separate the two sources of input to test them separately? The code currently does what I require, but it may need refactoring for easier testing.

```
Class Processor
    attr_accessor :card_hash

    def initialize
        @card_hash = Hash.new
    end

    def process
        while data = gets   
            if match = data.match(/(\D+) (\d+) \$(\d+)/) then
                name, card_num, limit = match.captures
                @card_hash [name] = Credit_card.new( name, card_num, limit)
....

describe Processor do

describe "#new" do
    before do
        @cp = Processor.new
    end
    it "returns a new Processor object" do
        expect(@cp).to be_an_instance_of Processor
    end 
    it "has an empty hash" do
        expect(@cp.card_hash).to be_empty
    end
end

describe '#process' do


    it "gets input from ARGV" do
        @cp = Processor.new
        expect(subject).to receive(:gets).with(no_args)

    end
   end

end
```

I have lost track of whether I'm trying to send input into the data variable to use testing the other parts of the code, or test that data receives the string from gets. Probably both. I've read about stubs and mocks and got rather confused. I've tried a lot of modifications from older questions (many with now deprecated syntax). I think I need a little help to get my ideas straightened out.
EDIT: I have finally gotten StringIO to send the data I need to initialize my object correctly to test it. It goes something like this:
`@input = StringIO.new('Test String')
 @array = [@input]
 @p = Processor.new(@array)`

Comment: Keep in mind there is not a universal 'right' way to write tests. If there are two methods your code is run, write two test cases to cover those. It can be as simple as that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this idea?

[EDITED]

For the main script…

```
require 'processor'
sources = ARGV.map{ |fname| File.open(fname) }
sources = [$stdin] if sources.empty?
Processor.new(sources).process
```

…and for processor.rb…

```
Class Processor
  attr_reader :sources
  attr_accessor :card_hash

  def initialize(sources)
    @sources = sources
    @card_hash = Hash.new
  end

  def process
    sources.each do |source|
      source.each_line.do |line|   
...
```

Then, for testing purposes, you can pass an array of one or more stub objects for the sources. The stub objects could be something like RSpec `double`s or an instances of `StringIO`. See http://apidock.com/ruby/StringIO .

Comment: You may be on the right path, but I would need something like: while data = ARGV ? $<.gets : File(ARGV[0]).gets because stdin alone doesn't work with giving a file name.

Comment: Your help got me as far as receiving an array with either file or stdin working. I still have a fundamental lack of understanding of the IO stubs though.  Plus, it looks like stubs and mocks are now deprecated, leaving only double?

Comment: An RSpec double can have mocking and/or stubbing behaviors. In any case, although you could use a double, I think a `StringIO` object might be more appropriate for what you're doing here.

Comment: Is this along the right path? `require 'stringio' @input = StringIO.new('A Test String')  p = Processor.new(@input) ` The method is expecting an Array with either STDIN or File input though. Placing the above` @input `into an array causes an odd error: `Failure/Error: @array = Array.new(@input)

     TypeError:
       no implicit conversion of StringIO into Integer`

Comment: `p = Processor.new([@input])`

Answer (score 2):

### Test Object Behavior, Not Implementation

In general, you will be a happier programmer if you test behavior rather than implementation. In this case, you have two main test cases:

1. You initialize your object with a filename.

   - Happy path: the file exists.
   - Sad path: the file doesn't exist.
2. You initialize your object without a filename.

   - Happy path: you receive data from STDIN or ARGV.
   - Sad paths:

     - STDIN and ARGV are both empty.
     - STDIN is closed.

If you follow this pattern, you will ensure that your object does the right thing regardless of how it's instantiated. You might use [StringIO](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/stringio/rdoc/StringIO.html) or [FakeFS](https://github.com/fakefs/fakefs) to isolate your tests from the actual filesystem, but you don't really need to be a purist about unit testing vs. integration testing as long as your tests are fast and **your tests validate the essential behaviors.**

Don't strive to be a completionist. Strive to perform the minimal testing necessary to validate the expected behavior of your object, and perhaps a few boundary conditions and edge cases to be on the safe side.